# Dynamic Page Title for both browser display and Google Analytics in Angular

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular-routing, page-title

### The question is:

How to dynamically and centrally set up Page Titles in Angular App only once for two purposes:

- to make a title in a browser reflect an actual page visited,
- to send a particular title to Google Analytics avoiding a boring, single and useless *Angular App* description applied to all app's pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### My current solution

I'v made use of two nice snippets found on Github:

- [first](https://gist.github.com/abarrak/448af33925e46257fefe0faf27f62e76) allows for defining Page Title centrally in Router config, just for visual purposes,
- [second](https://github.com/codediodeio/angular-gtag) provides a solution for sending navigation events to Google Analytics, while within a Single Page Application - in an automatic centralised way or manually. It's received an inspiring [ticket](https://github.com/codediodeio/angular-gtag/issues/7) commented by [amarnathm](https://github.com/amarnathm).

Well, the ideas presented in those two including the discussion on the [issue](https://github.com/codediodeio/angular-gtag/issues/7) reported to the latter may be integrated in this way:

**app.routing-module.ts**:

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  { path: 'site/contact', component: ContactComponent, data: {title: 'Contact'}},
  ...
  // other paths
];
```

**app.module.ts**:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {TitleService} from "./title.service";
import {GtagModule} from "angular-gtag";
// ...
providers: [
    // ...
    TitleService,
    GtagModule.forRoot({ trackingId: 'MY-UA-CODE', trackPageviews: false })        
    // ...   
  ]
// ...
```

`trackPageviews: false`, as proposed by [amarnathm](https://github.com/amarnathm), is important as we'll track manually per page. Standard sample code by [Jeff](https://github.com/codediodeio) defaults to `true`

**title.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { filter, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TitleService {
  default_title = 'My App';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private title: Title,
    private gtag: Gtag,
    private env: Environment
  ) { }

  boot() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.activeRoute),
      map(route => route.firstChild),
      switchMap(route => route.data),
      map((data) => {

        //here goes the GA reporting code            

        this.gtag.pageview({
          page_title: data && data.title ? data.title : this.default_title,
          page_path: this.router.url,
          page_location: this.env.host + this.router.url
        });

        return data && data.title ? `${data.title} • ${this.default_title}` : this.default_title;
      })
    ).subscribe((current_title) => this.title.setTitle(current_title));
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TitleService } from './title.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private titleService: TitleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.boot();
  }
}
```

Get rid of any GA/Gtag code you may have in your `index.html` file. This allows for customised subscription to GA services without relying on the automatic tracking we won't use. In SPA `index.html` is loaded usually once and without page tracking set on is useless.

### Enhancement proposal:

I'v got no answer for:

> How to make use of `ActivatedRoute` parameters and map them to
>   detailed titles used then in Analytics and optionally - for displaying
>   *per parameter* titles in a browser.

Comment: You don't have to specify the `Title` service from `@angular/platform-browser` in your app's module as this should already been defined in the `PlatformBrowserModule` that would've been defined in your app's module.

Comment: `BrowserModule` actually. Thank you @Edric, I've edited.